# init() err UHFOpenAndConnect result:-1 - getting this error inconsistently RFID Android Tablet

Tags: android, tablet, rfid

I am working with Chainway p80 tablet. It is android rfid tablet. I am able to get rfid to work. However at times the rfid fails and gives init() err UHFOpenAndConnect result:-1. The problem is with initiating RFID module within the tablet. It happens on and off and with many scenarios, I am not able to find the cause of this. if i wait for 15 min and then try again, it works. Below is the logcat.

```
D/DeviceAPI: GetUm7Hw() Status=-2
D/DeviceAPI: ----------UHFUHF_OpenAndConnect_Ex   GetUm7Hw(HwVersion) = 1 ----------
D/DeviceAPI: GetUm7Hw() Status=-2
D/DeviceAPI: UHF SLR5100_SendAndRev() sbuf[0] = ff
D/DeviceAPI: UHF SLR5100_SendAndRev() sbuf[1] = 0
UHF SLR5100_SendAndRev() sbuf[2] = 4
UHF SLR5100_SendAndRev() sbuf[3] = 1d
UHF SLR5100_SendAndRev() sbuf[4] = b
I/DeviceAPI_UHF: init() Uart = /dev/ttyMSM2
E/DeviceAPI_UHF: init() err UHFOpenAndConnect result:-1
D/mContext: com.rscja.deviceapi.RFIDWithUHFUART@5d3bc82
E/DeviceAPI_UHF: startInventory() err :-1
E/DeviceAPI_UHF: stopInventory() err :-1
I/MY: UHFReadTagFragment.onPause
```

I have added the code in as a fragment and as an Activity. Made sure that one file is calling the initUHF() so it doesn't interfere with the process.

Answer (score 0):

are you using chainway SDk following works for me.

```
      fun initializeReader() {

   try {
    mReader= RFIDWithUHFUART.getInstance()
  //  this.callBack?.onInitialized()
   }
   catch (ex: Exception) {
      Log.e("pre",ex.message.toString())
     //this.callBack?.onError(Error(Utility.EVENT_SCANNER_INITIALIZING_FAIL,""))

     }
 }
```

Comment: yes chainway. it seems like there is a glitch in their code. It initialize at time and other time it doesn't

Comment: @Ahsan did you find  way?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be late for this answer, but here is what was happening to me (Chainway U300):

The error:
`init() err UHFOpenAndConnect result:-1`

In my case the app was trying to open the '/dev/ttyS9' device but there was another application using that resource, so it threw the above error.

The solution: force the application to stop or disable the service, which by default uses the device we want to open with our app. In my case 'UHF Service' was the application that was causing conflict with my application. So I opened the app and stopped the service that was running.

Hope this is helpful!